# Get IntelliJ to recognize modified internal class method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In NetBeans I created a class: java.awt.Canvas (I use -XBootClassPath). In this class, I add a function call: "addPaintListener".

When I compile, it works fine. I can write code like (In netbeans. No errors):

```
public static void notifyCanvasReady(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.addPaintListener((PaintListener) g -> {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("HELLO WORLD", 50, 50);
    });
}
```

But in IntelliJ, it gives me an error:

[image]

---

However, if I Right-Click the project and hit compile module, it compiles fine (still shows the error) but actually runs regardless.

[image]

---

Any idea how I can get it to stop showing the error or get it to recognize my modified internal class?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that picture is big enough? I mean, someone might be reading this from 100 feet away and might have to squint... slightly.

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying internal classes -- this is what inheritance is for. Why don't you just extend it and provide a class with your own method on it? What you are doing is extremely unusual and probably isn't supported in IntelliJ.

Comment: @EngineerDollery; I'm really sorry about the image. I took a screenshot on my computer and when I uploaded it, it was super large. I took it on the MBP Retina Display. :( I don't know how to reduce the quality or shrink it. Example of just a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ULjlLeZ.png It's somehow super large on imgur.

Comment: Also, I'm hooking a function in a java application and that is the reason for overriding the behaviour internally. If I replace the Canvas class then when the jar loads, it actually uses my Canvas class instead. It's an easy way to hook function calls.

Comment: What you want is AspectJ and load-time weaving. It'll save you a lot of sleepless nights and it'll work even when you upgrade the jvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are right that you are not supposed to modify JDK classes, if you are not a JDK engineer. However let's assume you really want to do this.
The following should work:

- Go to the project settings `File | Project  Structure...`
- Click on `Modules` in the left panel
- Select your module in the middle panel (the one called *BotTutorial* I assume)
- Go to the `Dependencies` tab in the right panel
- Move `<Module source>` up above the JDK in the table using drag&drop or the arrow buttons at the bottom.

Here's what the dialog looks like. `<Module source>` should be at the top of the table, above the `1.7_15` JDK.
[image: Project Structure Module Dependencies]